# Android root explorer, that can write to system folders

Tags: gratis, android, open-source, file-management

My phone is rooted. I am looking for an open source file explorer that can read and write system folders (such as `/data`). Requirements:

- Available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/)
- Can write to system folders
- Usual file operations *(Copy-and-paste files/folders from anywhere to anywhere, Create/delete/rename folders, Delete/rename files)*
- Graphical user interface, as typing is not very convenient on a small device
- Comfortable to use on a medium-sized phone screen (for instance 5")

Tried:

- Cyanogenmod's File Manager: Good but it is not on F-Droid, for some reason
- [File Manager (forked from Cyanogenmod)](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ics): Says "*By default you can't access /data or /system but that can be changed by choosing a different security access mode in the General preferences*" but actually that menu is greyed out (installed from F-Froid)
- [File Manager PRO](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.michaldabski.filemanager): Can't see anything outside the SD card
- [Open Explorer Beta](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.brandroid.openmanager): "*no system write yet*"
- [Amaze](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.amaze.filemanager): Somehow did not allow me to paste files
- Root Browser: Not open source

Answer (score 2):

Not tried it myself, but you could give **[Ghost Commander](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.ghostsq.commander)** a try:

[image: Ghost] [image: Ghost]
<sup>*Ghost Commander* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander); click images for larger variants)</sup>

*Ghost Commander* seems to match all your requirements:

- **Available on F-Droid:** [Yes](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.ghostsq.commander)
- **Can write to system folders:** Yes. Quoting: *root / superuser (su) mode: remount partitions and make changes in system files*
- **Usual file operations:** I'd be surprised if not :) Even supports ZIP operations and FTP/SMB, file search, has a built-in editor, and more
- **Graphical user interface:** Yes (see screenshots).
- **Comfortable to use on a medium-sized phone screen:** Define "medium-sized". Nowadays, this could mean 5" to 6" #D Honestly: I've not tried it, but the screenshots suggest as much.

Next to F-Droid, *Ghost Commander* is also available at *Google Play* – and there it has a 4.5 star rating (at more than 11k votes), which speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0):

**[Simple Explorer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2330864)** is [open source](https://github.com/DF1E/SimpleExplorer) available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.dnielfe.manager) and lightweight:

[image]

It comes with root support, and even can deal with archives (TAR/RAR/ZIP). Its [feature list a.o. mentions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=45792334&postcount=47):

> - Root: delete, move, copy, create files and directorys, rename
> - Create file/folder
> - Move, copy, rename, delete, share
> - Bookmarks
> - Appmanager for APP backups

Comment: Can it write in / too?

Comment: What exactly meant by _write_?

Comment: @wingedpanther: For instance, can you copy one of your pictures to the `/data` folder? A screenshot showing that would be perfect :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  Yes only after giving root access, you can try it yourself, isn't it ?

Comment: @Izzy, LOL,Can't you [search](http://forum.xda-developers.com/thread-search/?threadid=2330864&query=root) in XDA for root,smh..?. And tons of thanks for your lecture about KEYWORD _WRITE_ :D !!

Comment: Sorry if I tapped on your toe, but I've thought "write access" too obvious a term :) As Nicolas already explained it "by example", I'll remove my comment(s) now for a cleanup. And sure I could have searched XDA for "root" and "write", but that would give far too many hits :) // Btw, one of the reasons Nicolas and me have joined in here for clarification is: according to our [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185), an answer a.o. should show how each requirement is met. We don't necessarily need such an app for ourselves, or wish to try each recommended app :)